# Why is my phyton mock only working with a specific way of import?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, testing, mocking

I have a utils class that besides other stuff has a function to get an id:

```
# utils.py
def get_id():
    return ...
```

Also, there is another class, lets say its about cars, that uses this function:

```
# car.py
from utils import get_id

class Car:
    ...
    def setup(self):
        self.id = get_id()
```

I want to run a unittest that should provide a specific id which is why I am mocking this function:

```
# test_car.py
import unittest
from unittest.Mock import Mock
import utils

class TestCar(unittest.TestCase):
    ...

    def test_car_setup(self):
        utils.get_id = Mock(callable, return_value="my-testing-id")
        car = Car()
        car.setup()
        ...
```

But this mock is not working. I still get the behavior of the original function.
However, I was able to get it working by adjusting the car class like this:

```
# car.py
from . import utils

class Car:
    ...
    def setup(self):
        self.id = utils.get_id()
```

The question is now, why is that working, and the previous version not?
I initially thought that this could be a call by reference/call by value issue, but the debugger showed that now matter how I adjust the imports, the utils function is always the same object.

I understand that this might not be a typical question because my projest is working, but I am failing to understand the workings of python that lead to it and I would appreciate if someone could enlighten me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The main idea with mocking is that you want to mock relative to where you are testing. So, you want to actually mock the `get_id` relative to the module path of where your `Car` class is (the actual entity you want to test), which in your example would be `car`. So your `get_id` method would be mocked using `@patch('car.get_id')` and not `@patch('utils.get_id')`. Take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch) to understand where to patch your methods. Hope this helps.

Comment: While this helps and maybe provides a better solution, my question was rather why the way I am importing affects this at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Change `test_car.py`

It is enough to make some changes to your file `test_car.py`, while `car.py` and `utils.py` remain without changes; the file `car.py` include the original import `from utils import get_id` as showed below:

```
# car.py
from utils import get_id

class Car:
    ...
    def setup(self):
        self.id = get_id()
```

Below I show you the file `test_car.py` with the needed modifications:

```
#test_car.py
import unittest
from unittest.mock import Mock
#import utils                      # <----- this import is now useless
from car import Car                # <----- add this import
import car as module_car           # <----- add this import (added the alias
                                   #        module_car to avoid name collision)

class TestCar(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_car_setup(self):
        # I have commented your instruction
        #utils.get_id = Mock(callable, return_value="my-testing-id")
        
        # USE THIS INSTRUCTION 
        module_car.get_id = Mock(callable, return_value="my-testing-id")
        car = Car()
        car.setup()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

#### Explanation

The most important change is the following:

```
utils.get_id = Mock(callable, return_value="my-testing-id") ---> module_car.get_id = Mock(callable, return_value="my-testing-id")
```

- The instruction `module_car.get_id = Mock(...)` substitutes the object pointed by the name `get_id` used inside the module `car.py`; this means that when is executed the instruction `self.id = get_id()` in the method `setup()` is executed the Mock object which returns `my-testing-id`
- Your instruction (`utils.get_id = Mock(...)`) substitutes the object pointed by name `get_id`, but inside the file `utils.py`; the error is that the object used by the method `setup()` is pointed by the name `get_id` defined inside `car.py`.

#### Why your second solution works

Your second solution is using the import `from . import utils` in the file `car.py` as showed below:

```
# car.py
from . import utils

class Car:
    ...
    def setup(self):
        self.id = utils.get_id()
```

In this way, **in your test code**,  the object pointed by `utils.get_id()` has been substituted by the Mock object (this is thanks to the instruction `utils.get_id = Mock(callable, return_value="my-testing-id")` present in your code).
So it happens:

```
utils.get_id() returns a reference which (points to) ----> Mock object
```

In the file `car.py` you use **exactly** the instruction: `utils.get_id()` and it returns a reference to the Mock.

#### Why your first solution doesn't work

The file `test_car.py` is the same both in the first and second solutions, so it is always true that:

```
utils.get_id() returns a reference which (points to) ----> Mock object
```

But your original file `car.py` is:

```
# car.py
from utils import get_id

class Car:
    ...
    def setup(self):
        self.id = get_id()
```

So in it, with the instruction `from utils import get_id` you define the name `get_id` and `get_id()` returns a reference to the object `get_id` defined inside the module `utils.py`.

In the method `setup()` you use directly `get_id()` (and not `utils.get_id()`); `get_id()` returns the reference to the real object and not to the mock object; the Mock object is returned only by `utils.get_id()`.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed alternative solution, i appreciate it. However, it is not really answering the actual question: Why is the way I am importing affecting this at all?

Apparently it is indeed a problem with different references, but I can't get the debugger to show me the prove. I always see the same memory address, that is confusing me.

Comment: @ningelsohn I have modified the answer. I have tried to add some details to understand why your second solution works and why the first solution doesn't work. Give me a feedback please. I don't know if my explanation can be sufficient. I'm sorry but I don't have the time to simulate all by debug and add details about the real id reference provided by the debugger.

Comment: Thank you! That clears it up pretty good and is absolutely logical. My confusion was mostly based on false assumptions about the functionality of the mock module.

Comment: Well I'm happy that my long answer help you to better understand the mocking in Python. Testing is one of reasons which has convinced me to use Python.